# Does Parrot have a database interface or API?

Tags: database, dbi, parrot

A quick search gave me this [announcement of Parrot DBDI](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbdi-dev@perl.org/msg00002.html) from January 2004 and a [dbdi-dev mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbdi-dev@perl.org/) which appears to be long dead. Is Parrot DBDI still being developed? Is anyone working on a different database API or interface for Parrot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBDI was an effort to create a database driver interface like the current DBI and DBD modules. It died, so developers are now using an existing interface instead - the Java JDBI. Two such developers are Tim Bunce (who worked on DBI 1, but hasn't had much time to work on its sequel) and Simon Cozens:

http://perlbuzz.com/2008/12/database-access-in-perl-6-is-coming-along-nicely.html

```
use DBDI;
my $conn = DBDI::DriverManager.getConnection(
    "dbdi:SQLite3:test.db", "", "");
my $stm = $conn.createStatement();
my $rs = $stm.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE foo (bar, baz)");
my $stm = $conn.prepareStatement(
    "    INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stm.setColumn(1, 123);
$stm.setColumn(2, "Thingy");
$stm.executeUpdate();
```

This module should be available to all Parrot languages, not just Perl 6.

---

Actually for Perl 6 we'll probably see an SQL quote operator so you can do stuff like this:

```
$conn.prepareStatement( Q:sql<INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES($bar, $baz)> );
```

And of course in Perl 6 quote modifiers like Q:sql can be abbreviated, e.g. to qs<> or sql<>

Answer (score 1):

From the [DBI::Roadmap 1.607](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.607/Roadmap.pod) manual, dated Nov 2004:

> The bulk of the work will be
>   translating the DBI C and Perl base
>   class code into Parrot PIR, or a
>   suitable language that generates PIR.
>   The project stalled, due to Parrot not
>   having key functionality at the time.
>   That has been resolved but the project
>   has not yet restarted.

This [post](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.dbdi.dev/2005/05/msg44.html) from Darren Duncan in May 2005:

> I believe it will start up again very
>   soon now.  See, a number of the  main
>   missing prerequisites are now coming
>   online, and so with those  in place we
>   can start work.

I can't find anything more recent than that.  Parrot itself is kind of glacial in its progress, so perhaps to remain compatible with the Parrot platform, DBDI is too.  :-)